# AAChartModel-Swift / AAInfographics — trouble displaying a chart

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [AAChartModel](https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartKit-Swift) Swift library.

I imported it, and did `import AAInfographics`.

I can't manage to get a chart to display. I have the following code as an `onAppear` on a VStack:

```swift
.onAppear {
    let chartModel = AAChartModel()
        .chartType(.bar)
            .title("Polar Area Chart")
            .subtitle("A simple polar area chart")
            .dataLabelsEnabled(true)
            .categories(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"])
            .yAxisTitle("Y-axis Title")
            .series([
                AASeriesElement()
                    .name("Polar Area Chart")
                    .data([7.0, 6.9, 2.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5])
            ])
    
    let chartView = AAChartView()
    chartView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                            y: 60,
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200)
    chartView.aa_drawChartWithChartModel(chartModel)
}
```

I get the following printed to console (ends with  `AAChartView was destroyed!!!`):

```bash
----------- console log AAOptions JSON information of AAChartView -----------:
{
  "series" : [
    {
      "data" : [
        7,
        6.9000000000000004,
        2.5,
        14.5,
        18.199999999999999,
        21.5
      ],
      "name" : "Polar Area Chart"
    }
  ],
  "legend" : {
    "enabled" : true
  },
  "xAxis" : {
    "categories" : [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun"
    ],
    "visible" : true,
    "labels" : {
      "enabled" : true
    },
    "title" : {
      "text" : ""
    }
  },
  "tooltip" : {
    "shared" : true,
    "enabled" : true
  },
  "subtitle" : {
    "text" : "A simple polar area chart"
  },
  "chart" : {
    "pinchType" : "none",
    "panning" : true,
    "type" : "bar"
  },
  "colors" : [
    "#1e90ff",
    "#ef476f",
    "#ffd066",
    "#04d69f",
    "#25547c"
  ],
  "plotOptions" : {
    "series" : {
      "stacking" : "",
      "animation" : {
        "duration" : 800,
        "easing" : 0
      },
      "dataLabels" : {
        "enabled" : true
      }
    },
    "bar" : {
      "borderWidth" : 0,
      "borderRadius" : 0
    }
  },
  "credits" : {
    "enabled" : false
  },
  "yAxis" : {
    "title" : {
      "text" : "Y-axis Title"
    },
    "visible" : true,
    "lineWidth" : 0,
    "labels" : {
      "enabled" : true
    },
    "gridLineWidth" : 0.60000002384185791
  },
  "title" : {
    "text" : "Polar Area Chart"
  }
}
 AAChartView was destroyed!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload chart just add here

```
let chartModel = AAChartModel()
    .chartType(.bar)
        .title("Polar Area Chart")
        .subtitle("A simple polar area chart")
        .dataLabelsEnabled(true)
        .categories(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"])
        .yAxisTitle("Y-axis Title")
        .series([
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Polar Area Chart")
                .data([7.0, 6.9, 2.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5])
        ])

let chartView = AAChartView()
chartView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                        y: 60,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200)
chartView.aa_drawChartWithChartModel(chartModel)
chartView.reload() here
```

Comment: I think the "here" in the code is incorrect, but I am not an Excel VBA user.